# Encrypt column SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, encryption, certificate, symmetric-key

I have a column in a table which needs to be encrypted for security reasons. How is this possible with SQL Server 2008?

I found this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx , but when I try to create the master key it gives me an error so I can't continue

I have never done this before, can someone explain it more for me?

Thanks,

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Mos_SchemaChangeMonitorDbTg, Line 8
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SCL_ObjectName', table 'CAMPUS365_PROD-ESEP-2014-09-30-1.mos.SchemaChangeLog'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a database trigger (called Mos_SchemaChangeMonitorDbTg) that is not correctly handling the creation of the master key. You will need to contact your DBA or admin team in order to get them to fix Mos_SchemaChangeMonitorDbTg before you can continue.